# Can't locate mysqldump file

Tags: mysql

I can't find my mysqldump file, I've trying searching in windows and using the command prompt, I've also tried specifying the destination file path.

Both below seem to work (with or without space between u and root), in that I'm prompted for a password, press return and a whole bunch of code scrolls through and the window closes.

I'm using MySQL through xampp with no password:

```
"C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -p --databases movie_cleanrun >movie.clean1.sql

"C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe" -uroot -p --databases movie_cleanrun >"C:\Users\Betty\movie_dump.sql"
```

Thanks

Comment: If you actually see the SQL queries scrolling through your window, it didn't work. That output should've been redirected to the file you entered. What version of Windows are you using? Those commands should just work fine.

Comment: You may want to try the [--result-file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file) option instead of redirecting, but I'm stumped as to why the commands you already tried don't work, that's just basic stuff that Windows should be able to handle.

Comment: I was being an idiot, it works now! thanks for your help